# Sort array by length in sequelize

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I use "sequelize". In the array, I store user ids. I need to sort by the number of elements in the array, that is, the more elements in the array, the higher it is in the list, the elements inside the array are not interesting to me.

```
return db.Books.findAll({
    limit: 5,
    include: [{
        model: db.User
    }],
    order: [
        ['likes']    // likes it's array
    ]
})
```

};

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of books ordered by the amount of some arbitrary model instances associated with it, let's assume `Like`, you can use a function to count the rows in `Like` that match the relation:

```
return db.Books.findAll({
    limit: 5,
    include: [{
        model: db.User
    },
    {
        model: db.Like,
        attributes:[
            [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', '*'), 'num_of_likes']
        ]
    }],
    order: [
        ['num_of_likes']    // likes it's array
    ]
});
```

Comment: I think that creating a table just to sort the number of likes is a bad idea. Anyway, thanks for the reply!

Comment: I need to know only the length of the array and sort only by length, the rest of the logic works on the client

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a function to order to get the number of elements in the array. I solved this problem as follows:

```
const posts = await this.postRepository.findAndCountAll({
        limit,
        offset: page * limit,
        order: [[fn('cardinality', col('usersLiked')), 'DESC']]
    })
```

Сardinality returns the total number of elements in the array, or 0 if the array is empty. "usersLiked" is my array in the table.